# Log Stack in Winston depending on error level

Tags: node.js, logging, winston

I want to log some the stack trace of an error depending on the level.
For example:
`logger.info`: `Something good happened`
`logger.error`: `Message: Some bad things happened \n Stack: some trace`
Is this possible?
Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:
You can use:

```js
format.printf(info => {
  if (info.level === 'info')
    {return info.message} 
}
```